Three.js libraries and what they extend in an outline or table view
Has anyone seen an outline or matrix showing which three.js libraries (or classes) extend other libraries? Ideally listing what functionality is added?
Maybe something like
src/core/Object3D is extended by src/objects/Line which is extended by src/objects/LineLoop and src/objects/LineSegments
but shown in a table or outline? The documentation shows this across the top of the write-up for each library in the src directory, but maybe someone has done this for the examples?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
